# Load HTTP header dictionary string into JSON and parse it

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, header, python-requests, http-headers

I have this HTTP header stored as a string. I want to load it in a JSON format to be able to:

1. Check if a header exists or not.
2. If the header does not exist, I need it to print `"no-header"`
3. If it exists, I need to check the existence and content of some chosen directives. For example, if `'Strict-Transport-Security'` is found, I need to check that it has a `max-age` directive. And that the `max-age` is 1111.

How to do this? My initial attempt is:

```
import json


mystring="{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 05:46:00 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=cp1251', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'}"
d = json.loads(mystring)

print(d['Strict-Transport-Security'])
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 5, in
<module>
    d = json.loads(mystring)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
 ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I need to load this string format (seems like a dictionary) and parse it to:

1. check the existence of a header name.
2. check its content against some defined criteria like contains, not contains, etc.

Comment: You already asked this question! Use `eval(mystring)` to turn it into a dictionary.

Comment: Plz provide a complete answer so I can get what you say. I do not get it.

Comment: I mean in coding plz.

Comment: I answered the question. I feel it was clear to begin with though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` uses double quotes instead of single quotes, so you can replace them:

```
mystring="{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 05:46:00 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=cp1251', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'}"
mystring = mystring.replace("'", '"')
>>> print(json.loads(mystring))
{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=cp1251', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 05:46:00 GMT'}
```

Or you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(mystring)
>>> print(d['Date'])
Fri, 19 Apr 2019 05:46:00 GMT
```

Comment: I can't replace the single quotes. The data inside the values are very complex and may contain single quotes that I should not change. So is the second code solve my problem?